# Is it possible to download the page and write my own styles?

Tags: webpack, gulp, webpack-dev-server, gulp-watch, hubspot

I use a Webpack to build code, and I also have a Hubspot YAML setup that sends the built code to Hubspot - I see changes in 3-5 seconds on a live page. I want to download target site and be able to write my own styles live. Is this possible in Webpack? I used it before in Gulp.js and it was possible.

I tried to use Webpack dev server, but I'm not able to download target page.